# SELECT count vs DELETE JOIN. Why/how are they different?

Tags: mysql, join, delete

Can someone explain in what way these queries could be different and the results are not the same?

```
> begin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)  

>select count(*) from tableA a JOIN tableB b ON (a.internal_id = b.internal_id) and a.customer_id=1001;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    23666 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.20 sec)   

>delete b.* from tableA a JOIN tableB b ON (a.internal_id = b.internal_id) and a.customer_id=1001;
Query OK, 23649 rows affected (0.74 sec)
```

Can someone please explain why the delete shows a different number of rows than the count? I am using the same join. Are they not equivalent?

Comment: Try using `select count(distinct b.pk)` where `pk` is the primary key of `b`. A row from `b` can match more than one rows from `a` but you can't delete it twice.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the count differs is due to multiple rows being present in tableA that have a foreign key reference to the same row in tableB.

When using an inner join the SELECT produces a separate row for each of the records in tableA.  The DELETE statement is only affects tableB.  As mentioned in ypercube's comment, if you were to do a distinct count, the numbers would match.